# useState with arrays not rerendering

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am facing issue while using useState hook with array. I checked various resources on stackoverflow, but could not fix it.

my basic code snippet looks like :

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  function addNewContact(user) {
    const newUsers = [...users,user];
    console.log(newUsers);
    setUsers(newUsers);
  }
```

```
<CardContainer users={users}></CardContainer>
```

```
class CardContainer extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("this -> ");
        console.log(this.props.users);
        this.state = {
            users: this.props.users
        }
    }

    render() {
        //console.log(this.state.users)
        return (
            <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-2 g-4">
                {
                    this.state.users.map(user => {
                        return <Card id={user.phone} title={user.name} email={user.email} phone={user.phone}></Card>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default CardContainer;
```

I am able to see updated array in the console, but the component using it is not rendering again. Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: we need to see the code for the card container. we need a fully reproducible example of code to work with

Comment: added the card container component

Comment: I would use a function component for the CardContainer.

Comment: Not necessarily will fix the issue, however, is important: first, you need to make sure that there is something to render, second you need to supply `key` property to mapped `<Card />` components, i.e. `this.state?.users?.map(user => {return <Card key={user.phone} id ={user.phone}..`

Comment: I intentionally used class based to have understanding of class based components

Comment: Don't reassign state from the parent to state in the child. The `constructor` is only called when the component mounts for the first time - now you have two sets of the same state you have to update and keep track of for no reason. Just pass `this.props.users` straight to the render of `CardContainer`.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov but that wont cause this current problem right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to you're storing the prop in the state of the child component, which is assigned on component initialization and component initialization/constructor only run one, until its remounted. After that, whenever, the state changes in the parent component, the child component is not re-rendering, because it uses its own state for map.

This below code only runs once on the component initialization.

```
this.state = {
   users: this.props.users
}
```

In the child component, you can directly use the props and the child component will always re-render on change in the parent component. Instead of `this.state.users.map` you can directly map the array from props like this `this.props.users.map`. This way,the component will re-render on state change in the parent compoenent.

Answer (score 1):

As @Junaid said, `constructor` is only called once before component mounting. If you really need to set a separate state inside the child component, then you can use `componentDidUpdate(prevProps)` react life cycle method. Make sure to compare previous and current props in order to avoid infinite loop of re-rendering.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.users !== prevProps.users) {
    this.setState({ users: this.props.users });
  }
};
```

Comment: I wouldn't do that, it's a waste of re-painting the component by making a state out of props! especially if there were no computations made, and even then it's possible just to create some variables for such computations.

Comment: could you please also help me that what would be a case where componentDidUpdate shall be appropriate to use ?

Comment: Yes, that's completely true and I completely agree with accepted answer. But it's only for the knowledge which can be helpful in some other cases. Let's say you need to invoke an api endpoint to fetch some data based on the props or state changes. Then you can use it in such cases. For more info. please visit https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate